# Flutter - Using API for charts with model

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

i've got stuck at this problem for nearly 3 days. Already post it in another questions but, got minus instead an answer.
Let me make it clear the questions.
I would like to put my api data using models into chart flutter, here is my code
First is my model here is my age model

**ages.dart**

```
  Ages agesFromJson(String str) => Ages.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String agesToJson(Ages data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

  class Ages {
    Ages({
      this.entity,
      this.code,
      this.year,
      this.underAge15,
      this.age1564,
      this.age65Over,
    });

    String entity;
    String code;
    int year;
    String underAge15;
    String age1564;
    String age65Over;

    factory Ages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ages(
          entity: json["entity"],
          code: json["code"],
          year: json["year"],
          underAge15: json["under_age_15"],
          age1564: json["age_15_64"],
          age65Over: json["age_65_over"],
        );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
          "entity": entity,
          "code": code,
          "year": year,
          "under_age_15": underAge15,
          "age_15_64": age1564,
          "age_65_over": age65Over,
        };
  }
```

and here i make the ages chart that given me the url from api and put into future builder

**ages_chart.dart**

```
    class AgeCharts extends StatefulWidget {
      final String url;

      const AgeCharts({this.url});

      @override
      _AgeChartsState createState() => _AgeChartsState();
    }

    class _AgeChartsState extends State<AgeCharts> {
      var chart;
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(widget.url);
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Japanese Age Working Populations'),
            ),
            body: Container(
              height: 400,
              child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                future: getChartData(widget),
                builder: (context, dataapi) {
                  if (dataapi.hasError) print(dataapi.error);
                  print(dataapi);
                  return dataapi.hasData
                      ? ShowChart(
                          data: dataapi.data,
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

after ages dart, i make a function to get an api.

```
  Future<List> getChartData(widget) async {
    final response = await http.get(widget.url);
    return json.decode(response.body)['data'];
  }
```

and here is my show chart when i already get an url

```
  class ShowChart extends StatelessWidget {
    final List data;

    ShowChart({this.data});

    static List<charts.Series<Ages, dynamic>> _createSampleData(dataAPI) {
      return [
        new charts.Series<Ages, dynamic>(
          id: 'Desktop',
          // colorFn specifies that the line will be blue.
          colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
          // areaColorFn specifies that the area skirt will be light blue.
          areaColorFn: (_, __) =>
              charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault.lighter,
          domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
          measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => int.parse(ages.underAge15),
          data: dataAPI,
        ),
        new charts.Series<Ages, dynamic>(
          id: 'Tablet',
          // colorFn specifies that the line will be red.
          colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
          // areaColorFn specifies that the area skirt will be light red.
          areaColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault.lighter,
          domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
          measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => int.parse(ages.age1564),
          data: dataAPI,
        ),
        new charts.Series<Ages, dynamic>(
          id: 'Mobile',
          // colorFn specifies that the line will be green.
          colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
          // areaColorFn specifies that the area skirt will be light green.
          areaColorFn: (_, __) =>
              charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault.lighter,
          domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
          measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => int.parse(ages.age65Over),
          data: dataAPI,
        ),
      ];
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      print('showchart');
      print(data);
      return Container(
        child: charts.LineChart(
          _createSampleData(data),
          defaultRenderer:
              new charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
          animate: true,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

this is my JSON Structure. but i get the data when using json.decode(response.body)

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Chart found",
"data": [
    {
        "entity": "Japan",
        "code": "JPN",
        "year": 1950,
        "under_age_15": "29288.106",
        "age_15_64": "49447.555",
        "age_65_over": "4066.423"
    },
    {
        "entity": "Japan",
        "code": "JPN",
        "year": 1951,
        "under_age_15": "29652.515",
        "age_15_64": "50461.828",
        "age_65_over": "4201.922"
    },
   ]
 }
```

and the i got an error like this

```
 type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Ages>'
```

help me solve the problem, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems within your code:

1. You are explicitly casting your series data as `charts.Series<Ages, dynamic>` while it should be `charts.Series<Ages, num>`
2. You are trying to parse double as int. If you want doubles, use `double.parse(x)` otherwise, `double.parse(x).round()` will give you a int. (or `.floor()` or `.ceil()`)
3. You should probably also specify your domain axis as not being zeroBound:

```
charts.LineChart(
  _createSampleData(data),
  defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
  animate: true,
  domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
    tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false),
  ),
),
```

### Working Solution

[image]

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Charts Demo',
      home:
          AgeCharts(url: 'http://udacoding-task-api.herokuapp.com/api/charts'),
    ),
  );
}

// MAIN WIDGET

class AgeCharts extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const AgeCharts({this.url});

  @override
  _AgeChartsState createState() => _AgeChartsState();
}

class _AgeChartsState extends State<AgeCharts> {
  var chart;

  Future<List<Ages>> getChartData(widget) async {
    final response = await http.get(widget.url);
    final List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
    return jsonData.map((data) => Ages.fromJson(data)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Japanese Age Working Populations'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: getChartData(widget),
            builder: (context, dataapi) {
              if (dataapi.hasError) print(dataapi.error);
              return dataapi.hasData
                  ? ShowChart(data: dataapi.data)
                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CHART

class ShowChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Ages> data;

  ShowChart({this.data});

  static List<charts.Series<Ages, num>> _createSampleData(dataAPI) {
    return [
      new charts.Series<Ages, num>(
        id: 'underAge15',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        areaColorFn: (_, __) =>
            charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault.lighter,
        domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
        measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => double.parse(ages.underAge15).round(),
        data: dataAPI,
      ),
      new charts.Series<Ages, num>(
        id: 'age1564',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
        areaColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault.lighter,
        domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
        measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => double.parse(ages.age1564).round(),
        data: dataAPI,
      ),
      new charts.Series<Ages, num>(
        id: 'age65Over',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
        areaColorFn: (_, __) =>
            charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault.lighter,
        domainFn: (Ages ages, _) => ages.year,
        measureFn: (Ages ages, _) => double.parse(ages.age65Over).round(),
        data: dataAPI,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: charts.LineChart(
        _createSampleData(data),
        defaultRenderer:
            new charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
        animate: true,
        domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          tickProviderSpec:
              charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// DOMAIN

class Ages {
  Ages({
    this.entity,
    this.code,
    this.year,
    this.underAge15,
    this.age1564,
    this.age65Over,
  });

  String entity;
  String code;
  int year;
  String underAge15;
  String age1564;
  String age65Over;

  factory Ages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ages(
        entity: json["entity"],
        code: json["code"],
        year: json["year"],
        underAge15: json["under_age_15"],
        age1564: json["age_15_64"],
        age65Over: json["age_65_over"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "entity": entity,
        "code": code,
        "year": year,
        "under_age_15": underAge15,
        "age_15_64": age1564,
        "age_65_over": age65Over,
      };
}

// DATA

math.Random random = math.Random();

final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  "status": true,
  "message": "Chart found",
  "data": List.generate(
      20,
      (index) => {
            "entity": "Japan",
            "code": "JPN",
            "year": 1950 + index,
            "under_age_15": (25000 + random.nextInt(5000)).toString(),
            "age_15_64": (40000 + random.nextInt(5000)).toString(),
            "age_65_over": (3000 + random.nextInt(2000)).toString(),
          }).toList(),
};
```

---

### BEFORE ANSWER UPDATE:

Try this:

```
Future<List<Ages>> getChartData(widget) async {
  final response = await http.get(widget.url);
  return json.decode(response.body)['data'].map((jsonData) => Ages.fromJson(jsonData)).toList();
}
```

I'm not 100% sure, since I don't know the structure of your JSON Data.

Comment: thank your for answering, i've already edited my questions :D

Comment: after i change the api into your answer i got another error, type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Ages>>'

Comment: I found 3 main problems in your code. Answer updated.

Comment: i tried your code above, using math random and it can generate. but when i change it into my json it become a problem Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast) .. btw this is where i get my api http://udacoding-task-api.herokuapp.com/api/charts..

Comment: I updated the solution to use your real data set.

Comment: wawww.. thank you.. you are a livesaver,how can i repay u?